# <ul> interfering with <a> tag

Tags: html, css

Here's my HTML structure:

```
<div id="Syllabus" class="syl">
    <a href="#">
    </a>
    <ul class="ul_menu">
        <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And here's my CSS:

```css
#Syllabus a {
    position:          absolute;
    top:               0px;
    left:              130px;
    width:             112px;
    height:            40px;
    background-image:  url(/Assets/Syb_but.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#Syllabus a:hover {
    background-image: url(/Assets/QuesPap_but_ul.png);
}

.ul_menu {
    position: relative;
    top:      44px;
    left:     43px;
    display:  none;
}

ul, li {
    margin:  auto;
    padding: 0;
}
```

When I view this code in any browser, the `background-image: url(/Assets/Syb_but.png);` is generated everytime by the `<li>` tag. That is, the `sym_but.png` appears on the right of `link1` and `link2` along with the initial one.

Comment: Your code is horribly formatted. Use a consistent indention space and adhere to it. It will help you read your code better too.

Answer (score 3):

`#Syllabus a` is a descendant selector. That means the rule is applied to all anchors that are descendant of #Syllabus.

Using a child selector would select only anchors that are direct children of #Syllabus: `#Syllabus > a`.

```
#Syllabus > a {
    position:          absolute;
    top:               0px;
    left:              130px;
    width:             112px;
    height:            40px;
    background-image:  url(/Assets/Syb_but.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#Syllabus > a:hover {
    background-image: url(/Assets/QuesPap_but_ul.png);
}

.ul_menu {
    position: relative;
    top:      44px;
    left:     43px;
    display:  none;
}

ul, li {
    margin:  auto;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: The same would be applied for the `a:hover` rule.

Comment: True. Strangely though, this 'issue' doesn't occur to me; the background-image is shown only once. Also the links(text) don't show, I just see the background image (once).

Answer (score 1):

What @jussinen said is right, you can use other solution too, giving specifics classes for the links. For example:

**HTML**

```
<div id="Syllabus" class="syl">
    <a href="#" class="link-level-one">
    </a>
    <ul class="ul_menu">
        <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#Syllabus a.link-level-one{
position:          absolute;
top:               0px;
left:              130px;
width:             112px;
height:            40px;
background-image:  url(/Assets/Syb_but.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#Syllabus a.link-level-one:hover {
background-image: url(/Assets/QuesPap_but_ul.png);
}

.ul_menu {
position: relative;
top:      44px;
left:     43px;
display:  none;
}

ul, li {
margin:  auto;
padding: 0;
}
```

Hope this can help you